# How to change Joomla site name from backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have tried to install Joomla 3.8.x on AWS using cloud formation template. I am able to install Joomla website but after installing the site Joomla site name is default listed as "joomla!".i am trying to install Joomla with the unique site name but I am unable to find which table contains Joomla site name information in the Joomla database. I can able to the change the   Joomla site name from admin panel after the installation but currently, I am searching for which table contains Joomla main configuration information.

Comment: Please post your Joomla-specific questions on Joomla Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name on which your Joomla.com website is accessed through the Change Name option. It is located in the options menu (gear icon) for the specific site in your admin panel

[two simple steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mg1RJ.png)